# SonarQube coverage showing 0% even after exclusion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, code-coverage

I been working on a SpringBoot project and I am trying to exclude some of the packages from the SonarQube code coverage.

The package that I want to exclude is **com.org.projectname.model**. I tried, `<sonar.exclusions>**/model/*.java</sonar.exclusions>` and `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/model/*.java</sonar.coverage.exclusions>`, sill SonarQube is showing 0% coverage, why is that?. Also I am curious that, do we need to have any specific dependency to use <sonar.exclusions>, as I am not using any additional dependency related to SonarQube?

or is there any other way to achieve this?

```
<properties>
       <sonar.exclusions>
          **/model/*.java
        </sonar.exclusions>
</properties>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
   <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.6</version>
   <configuration>
      <excludes>
      
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>pre-unit-test</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <destFile>target/coverage-data/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>post-unit-test</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <dataFile>target/coverage-data/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
            <outputDirectory>target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this may help you https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#:~:text=To%20use%20exclusions%20to%20analyze%20only%20the%20specified%20subset(s,Settings%20%3E%20Analysis%20Scope%20%3E%20Files.&text=You%20can%20set%20these%20properties%20at%20both%20the%20project%20and%20global%20levels.

Comment: Not sure of your setup but could you try <sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/com/org/projectname/model/*</sonar.exclusions>

Comment: If you're getting 0% coverage in SonarQube, your exclusions won't make any difference.  I notice that you're referencing the "jacoco-ut.exec" file.  At some point the "exec" format was deprecated in favor of the "xml" format, which has to go with setting a particular sonarqube property (sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths). You might want to look at your jacoco results in your build artifacts and see whether those are reporting 0% coverage. It's likely that you're getting non-zero coverage from jacoco, just not reporting it properly to sonarqube.